# proper hibernate annotation for byte[]

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, blob

I have an application using hibernate 3.1 and JPA annotations.  It has a few objects with byte[] attributes (1k - 200k in size).  It uses the JPA @Lob annotation, and hibernate 3.1 can read these just fine on all major databases -- it seems to hide the JDBC Blob vendor peculiarities (as it should do).

```
@Entity
public class ConfigAttribute {
  @Lob
  public byte[] getValueBuffer() {
    return m_valueBuffer;
  }
}
```

We had to upgrade to 3.5, when we discovered that hibernate 3.5  [breaks (and won't fix)](http://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4876) this annotation combination in postgresql (with no workaround).  I have not found a clear fix so far, but I did notice that if I just remove the @Lob, it uses the postgresql type bytea (which works, but only on postgres).

```
annotation                   postgres     oracle      works on
-------------------------------------------------------------
byte[] + @Lob                oid          blob        oracle
byte[]                       bytea        raw(255)    postgresql
byte[] + @Type(PBA)          oid          blob        oracle
byte[] + @Type(BT)           bytea        blob        postgresql

once you use @Type, @Lob seems to not be relevant
note: oracle seems to have deprecated the "raw" type since 8i.
```

I am looking for a way to have a single annotated class (with a blob property) which is portable across major databases.

- What is the portable way to annotate a byte[] property?
- Is this fixed in some recent version of hibernate?

**Update:**
After reading [this blog](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/PostgreSQLAndBLOBs#comment15505) I have finally figured out what the original workaround in the JIRA issue was: Apparently you are supposed to drop @Lob and annotate the property as:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveByteArrayBlobType") 
byte[] getValueBuffer() {...
```

However, this does not work *for me* -- I still get OIDs instead of bytea; it did however work for the author of the JIRA issue, who seemed to want oid.

After the answer from A. Garcia, I then tried this combo, which actually does work on postgresql, but not on oracle.

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType") 
byte[] getValueBuffer() {...
```

What I really need to do is control which @org.hibernate.annotations.Type the combination (@Lob + byte[] gets mapped) to (on postgresql).

---

Here is the snippet from 3.5.5.Final from MaterializedBlobType (sql type Blob).  According to Steve's blog, postgresql wants you to use Streams for bytea (don't ask me why) and postgresql's custom Blob type for oids.  Note also that using setBytes() on JDBC is also for bytea (from past experience).  So this explains why use-streams has no affect they both assume 'bytea'.

```
public void set(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) {
 byte[] internalValue = toInternalFormat( value );
 if ( Environment.useStreamsForBinary() ) {
  // use streams = true
   st.setBinaryStream( index, 
    new ByteArrayInputStream( internalValue ), internalValue.length );
 }
 else {
  // use streams = false
  st.setBytes( index, internalValue );
 }
}
```

This results in:

```
ERROR: column "signature" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea
```

**Update**
The next logical question is: "why not just change the table definitions manually to bytea" and keep the (@Lob + byte[])?  This *does* work, **UNTIL** you try to store a null byte[].  Which the postgreSQL driver thinks is an OID type expression and the column type is bytea -- this is because hibernate (rightly) calls JDBC.setNull() instead of JDBC.setBytes(null) which PG driver expects.

```
ERROR: column "signature" is of type bytea but expression is of type oid
```

The type system in hibernate is currently a 'work in progress' (according to 3.5.5 deprecation comment).  In fact so much of the 3.5.5 code is deprecated, it is hard to know what to look at when sub-classing the PostgreSQLDialect).

AFAKT, Types.BLOB/'oid' on postgresql should be mapped to some custom type which uses OID style JDBC access (i.e. PostgresqlBlobType object and NOT MaterializedBlobType).  I've never actually successfully used Blobs with postgresql, but I do know that bytea just simply works as one / I would expect.

I am currently looking at the BatchUpdateException -- its possible that the driver doesn't support batching.

---

Great quote from 2004:
 "To sum up my ramblings, I'd say they we should wait for the JDBC driver to do LOBs properly before changing Hibernate."

**References:**

- https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2393203
- https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2435174
- http://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4617
- http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Migration-to-Hibernate-3-5-final-td2175339.html
- https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-2318
- https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2203382&sid=b526a17d9cf60a80f13d40cf8082aafd
- http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/jpa-postgresql-and-bytea-vs-oid-type/

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in 3.6, not sure about 3.5.6; the MaterializedBlobType class was totally re-written from 3.5.5 > 3.6.  The OID type now works since they changed implementation.

Comment: Nice! I wonder what Jira issue is tracking this rewrite, if any (maybe the rewrite is a consequence of a deeper change). It would be nice to backport the changes in 3.5, if possible. Bad news if it's not possible.

Comment: Actually my test gave me a false positive the first time around (knew I should have waited!) -- its still not fixed, the bug has just moved to BlobTypeDescriptor.

Comment: Thanks. @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType") worked for me for a table that storage PDF files. I migrated a database from Oracle to Postgres using Oracle-To-PostgreSQL from Intelligent Converters, and it automatically converted and inserted from BLOB to BYTEA but BlobType didn't worked for me.

Comment: No fun for us that need a generic mapping to use for multiple RDBMSs... I cannot have one type mapped for SQLServer and one for PostgrSQL

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> What is the portable way to annotate a byte[] property?

It depends on what you want. JPA can persist a non annotated `byte[]`. From the JPA 2.0 spec:

> #### 11.1.6 Basic Annotation
>
> The `Basic` annotation is the simplest
>   type of mapping to a database column.
>   The `Basic` annotation can be applied
>   to a persistent property or instance
>   variable of any of the following
>   types: Java primitive, types, wrappers
>   of the primitive types,
>   `java.lang.String`,
>   `java.math.BigInteger`,
>   `java.math.BigDecimal`,
>   `java.util.Date`,
>   `java.util.Calendar`, `java.sql.Date`,
>   `java.sql.Time`, `java.sql.Timestamp`,
>   **`byte[]`, `Byte[]`**, `char[]`, `Character[]`, enums, and any other
>   type that implements `Serializable`.
>   As described in Section 2.8, the use
>   of the `Basic` annotation is optional
>   for persistent fields and properties
>   of these types. If the Basic
>   annotation is not specified for such a
>   field or property, the default values
>   of the Basic annotation will apply.

And Hibernate will map a it "by default" to a SQL `VARBINARY` (or a SQL `LONGVARBINARY` depending on the `Column` size?) that PostgreSQL handles with a `bytea`.

But if you want the `byte[]` to be stored in a Large Object, you should use a `@Lob`. From the spec:

> #### 11.1.24 Lob Annotation
>
> A `Lob` annotation specifies that a
>   persistent property or field should be
>   persisted as a large object to a
>   database-supported large object type.
>   Portable applications should use the
>   `Lob` annotation when mapping to a
>   database `Lob` type. The `Lob` annotation
>   may be used in conjunction with the
>   Basic annotation or with the
>   `ElementCollection` annotation when the
>   element collection value is of basic
>   type. A `Lob` may be either a binary or
>   character type. The `Lob` type is
>   inferred from the type of the
>   persistent field or property and,
>   except for string and character types,
>   defaults to Blob.

And Hibernate will map it to a SQL `BLOB` that PostgreSQL handles with a `oid`
.

> Is this fixed in some recent version of hibernate?

Well, the problem is that I don't know what the problem is exactly. But I can at least say that nothing has changed since 3.5.0-Beta-2 (which is where a changed has been introduced)in the 3.5.x branch.

But my understanding of issues like [HHH-4876](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4876), [HHH-4617](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4617) and of [PostgreSQL and BLOBs](http://relation.to/Bloggers/PostgreSQLAndBLOBs) (mentioned in the javadoc of the  `PostgreSQLDialect`) is that you are supposed to set the following property

```
hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=false
```

if you want to use `oid` i.e. `byte[]` with `@Lob` (which is my understanding since `VARBINARY` is not what you want with Oracle). Did you try this?

As an alternative, [HHH-4876](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4876) suggests using the deprecated `PrimitiveByteArrayBlobType` to get the old behavior (pre Hibernate 3.5).

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 2.8 "Mapping Defaults for Non-Relationship Fields or Properties"
  - Section 11.1.6 "Basic Annotation"
  - Section 11.1.24 "Lob Annotation"

#### Resources

- http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4876
- http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4617
- http://relation.to/Bloggers/PostgreSQLAndBLOBs

Comment: OMG, I realize this question has changed a lot since I started answering. Will read all the changes later and update my answes after digesting the changes if necessary.

Comment: Its good to see the spec, so hibernate is totally correct to map (@Lob + byte[]) to a large object supported type.  In Postgresql there are 2 (bytea or oid).  However, while hibernate 3.5 maps to oid (by default) it reads using JDBC getBytes() which PGSQL driver returns the 6 byte oid instead of the data.  Note also that the blog author has responded most helpfully (on his blog) since the question was posed.

Comment: @Justin *However, while hibernate 3.5 maps to oid (by default) it reads using JDBC getBytes() which PGSQL driver returns the 6 byte oid instead of the data* - does this occur when using `hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=false` too? (going to check what Steve said now).

Comment: I am going to try specifying it in the properties file, however PostgreSQLDialect has useInputStreamToInsertBlob() returning false so I assume that I am -- since I am not explicitly setting this property.

Comment: After setting this property (to either true or false), I get a runtime exception: ERROR: column "signature" is of type bytea but expression is of type oid".  I should mention I am using hibernate 3.5.5.Final + PG 8.2 drivers.

Comment: @Justin Hmm... Why is the error reporting about bytea? What did you try exactly? `@Lob byte[]` + `hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=false`?

Comment: This seems strange to me as well -- i double checked the db (no bytea anywhere) I need to hunt down the source of that message.  I've tried streams both false and true (@Lob + byte[]).  All give the same error when saving an object with a blob.  Only thing that works seems to be @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType") when using bytea.

Comment: @Justin `All give the same error when saving an object with a blob.` This is very disappointing given that it's the advice given by Hibernate developers :S. `Only thing that works seems to be @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType") when using bytea` This is what you'd get without the @Lob. But it won't work with Oracle, right? I think you'll have to customize the Dialect for a portable solution.

Comment: Either that or my setup is messed up, perhaps I need to up the version of hibernate or postgres.  I tried with both 8.2 and 8.4 drivers -- nothing so far :(

Comment: @Justin Not sure upgrading Hibernate beyond 3.5.0-Beta-2 will change anything. And if I understand things correctly, Postgres introduced this change in 7.2. What I don't get is the initial recommendation of Steve blog post as it doesn't seem to work (and in the current state, it seems that the change made in Hibernate does break something that was working). I must be missing something...

Comment: My updated question explains why it does not work.  Do you know if there is a hibernate test matrix?  Unless his blog is talking about a different release of hibernate, the advice does not seem to have been tested.

Comment: @Justin I'll read all this, including the blog post, carefully tonight. But to my knowledge, the blog is talking about Hibernate 3.5.0-Beta-2+ and the changes introduced by [HHH-4405](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4405) and [HHH-3892](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3892) so I'm tempted to think that you are right. Honestly, I still don't understand all the reasons for these changes and, somehow, they seem to break something.

Answer (score 11):

Here goes what O'reilly Enterprise JavaBeans, 3.0 says

> JDBC has special types for these very large objects. **The java.sql.Blob type represents binary data**, and java.sql.Clob represents character data.

Here goes PostgreSQLDialect source code

```
public PostgreSQLDialect() {
    super();
    ...
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "bytea");
    /**
      * Notice it maps java.sql.Types.BLOB as oid
      */
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "oid");
}
```

So what you can do

Override PostgreSQLDialect as follows

```
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();

        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "bytea");
    }
}
```

Now just define your custom dialect

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="br.com.ar.dialect.CustomPostgreSQLDialect"/>
```

And use your portable JPA @Lob annotation

```
@Lob
public byte[] getValueBuffer() {
```

**UPDATE**

Here has been extracted [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4BBF38F9.3080708@serhmatica.com.br)

> I have an application running in *hibernate 3.3.2 and the applications works fine*, with all blob fields using oid (byte[] in java)

...

> Migrating to *hibernate 3.5 all blob fields not work anymore*, and the server log shows: ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: column is of type oid but expression is of type bytea

**which can be explained** [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201004121828.52833.rsmogura@softperience.eu)

> This generaly *is not bug in PG JDBC*, **but change of default implementation of Hibernate in 3.5 version**. In my situation **setting compatible property on connection
>   did not helped**.

...

> Much more this what I saw in 3.5 - beta 2, and i do not know if this was fixed is Hibernate - without @Type annotation - **will auto-create column of type oid, but will try to read this as bytea**

Interesting is because when he maps Types.BOLB as bytea (See CustomPostgreSQLDialect) He get

> Could not execute JDBC batch update

when inserting or updating

Comment: This solution looks glorious, I am trying it now.

Comment: This generates the correct DDL, but fails at runtime:  I get a java.sql.BatchUpdateException when trying to an object with a blob property.

Comment: @Justin Try a similar scenario by using Oracle instead of PostgreSQL and see what you get. BatchUpdateException has to do with errors that occurs during a batch update operation.

Comment: Actually what I really want is not to map BLOB to "bytea" but instead map (byte[] + @Lob) annotation combination to Types.VARBINARY!

Comment: @Justin See http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html

Comment: @Justin Interesting, Although i do not use Postgres, PostgreSQLDialect maps standard *Types.VARBINARY* as **bytea**. So i think Postgres does not support native SQL Types.VARBINARY. See http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#VARBINARY It has been clear: **It identifies the generic SQL type VARBINARY**

Comment: Thanks for the research, I am currently trying all combinations of drivers and some variations of hibernate.  I even checked the value of `Environment.useStreamsForBinary()` to make sure I was setting the global property.

Comment: This solution will not work, you would need also to change reading in PgResultSet, since it's expecting OID and it's hardcoded.

Comment: I was already subclassing the PostgreSQL dialect for other functionality apparently missing or not working correctly so this solution worked fine for me without impacting other databases.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the Hibernate 4.2.7.SP1 with Postgres 9.3 and following works for me:

```
@Entity
public class ConfigAttribute {
  @Lob
  public byte[] getValueBuffer() {
    return m_valueBuffer;
  }
}
```

as Oracle has no trouble with that, and for Postgres I'm using custom dialect:

```
public class PostgreSQLDialectCustom extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {

    @Override
    public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor) {
    if (sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType() == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
      return BinaryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    }
    return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
  }
}
```

the advantage of this solution I consider, that I can keep hibernate jars untouched.

For more Postgres/Oracle compatibility issues with Hibernate, see my [blog post](http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.de/2014/03/postgres-and-oracle-compatibility-with_4.html).

Comment: Worked for me using Hibernate 4.3.6 and Postgresql 9.3 with extending Postgresql9Dialect. Thank you!

Comment: Works with Hibernate 5.3.7.Final and Postgres95Dialect. Thx

Answer (score 7):

I have finally got this working.  It expands on the solution from A. Garcia, however, since the problem lies in the hibernate type MaterializedBlob type just mapping Blob > bytea is not sufficient, we need a replacement for MaterializedBlobType which works with hibernates broken blob support.  This implementation only works with bytea, but maybe the guy from the JIRA issue who wanted OID could contribute an OID implementation.

Sadly replacing these types at runtime is a pain, since they should be part of the Dialect.
If only [this JIRA enhanement](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5584) gets into 3.6 it would be possible.

```
public class PostgresqlMateralizedBlobType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<byte[]> {
 public static final PostgresqlMateralizedBlobType INSTANCE = new PostgresqlMateralizedBlobType();

 public PostgresqlMateralizedBlobType() {
  super( PostgresqlBlobTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
 }

  public String getName() {
   return "materialized_blob";
  }
}
```

Much of this could probably be static (does getBinder() really need a new instance?), but I don't really understand the hibernate internal so this is mostly copy + paste + modify.

```
public class PostgresqlBlobTypeDescriptor extends BlobTypeDescriptor implements SqlTypeDescriptor {
  public static final BlobTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new PostgresqlBlobTypeDescriptor();

  public <X> ValueBinder<X> getBinder(final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
   return new PostgresqlBlobBinder<X>(javaTypeDescriptor, this);
  }
  public <X> ValueExtractor<X> getExtractor(final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
   return new BasicExtractor<X>( javaTypeDescriptor, this ) {
    protected X doExtract(ResultSet rs, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException { 
      return (X)rs.getBytes(name);
    }
   };
  }
}

public class PostgresqlBlobBinder<J> implements ValueBinder<J> {
 private final JavaTypeDescriptor<J> javaDescriptor;
 private final SqlTypeDescriptor sqlDescriptor;

 public PostgresqlBlobBinder(JavaTypeDescriptor<J> javaDescriptor, SqlTypeDescriptor sqlDescriptor) { 
  this.javaDescriptor = javaDescriptor; this.sqlDescriptor = sqlDescriptor;
 }  
 ...
 public final void bind(PreparedStatement st, J value, int index, WrapperOptions options) 
 throws SQLException {
  st.setBytes(index, (byte[])value);
 }
}
```

Comment: +1 for your research. Congratulations. Just an advice: Prefer to edit your own question/answer up to 8 times. Otherwise, your question/answer *will become community wiki* and you will not gain reputation and UP vote will not be computed anymore

Comment: Live and learn I suppose, I had so many edits, as I kept forgetting to do one thing or other with my test environment.

Comment: Same here, +1 for the research and *a* solution for your situation.

Comment: any chance for solution with 4.2.x Hibernate version? Hibernate internals have changed a bit (I commented issue reffered: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5584).

Answer (score 6):

i fixed My issue by adding the annotation of @Lob which will create the byte[] in oracle as blob , but this annotation will create the field as oid which not work properly , To make byte[] created as bytea i made customer Dialect for postgres as below

```
Public class PostgreSQLDialectCustom extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {
    public PostgreSQLDialectCustom() {
        System.out.println("Init PostgreSQLDialectCustom");
        registerColumnType( Types.BLOB, "bytea" );

      }

    @Override
    public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor) {
    if (sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType() == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
      return BinaryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    }
    return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
  }
 }
```

Also need to override parameter for the Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.ntg.common.DBCompatibilityHelper.PostgreSQLDialectCustom

more hint can be found her : https://dzone.com/articles/postgres-and-oracle

Comment: Thanks. Very good for those of us that need to have multiple dialects supported in a single application. This way I can have a mapping for materialized_blob work for Oracle, DB2, SQLServer, MySQL and H2, and yet get PostgreSQL to play nice. Using Postgres 14.5, Hibernate 5.6.7

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate 6+, javaee 9+

```
  @Lob
  @JdbcTypeCode(Types.BINARY)
  public byte[] getValueBuffer() {
    return m_valueBuffer;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Postgres @Lob is breaking for byte[] as it tries to save it as oid, and for String also same problem occurs. Below code is breaking on postgres which is working fine on oracle.

```
@Lob
private String stringField;
```

and

```
@Lob
private byte[]   someByteStream;
```

In order to fix above on postgres have written below custom hibernate.dialect

```
public class PostgreSQLDialectCustom extends PostgreSQL82Dialect{

public PostgreSQLDialectCustom()
{
    super();
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "bytea");
}

 @Override
 public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor) {
    if (Types.CLOB == sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType()) {
      return LongVarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    }
    return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
  }
}
```

Now configure custom dialect in hibernate

```
hibernate.dialect=X.Y.Z.PostgreSQLDialectCustom
```

X.Y.Z is package name.

Now it working fine. 
NOTE- My Hibernate version - 5.2.8.Final 
      Postgres version- 9.6.3

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use in the entity

```java
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
@Column(name = "stringField")
private byte[] stringField;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by overriding annotation with XML file for Postgres. Annotation is kept for Oracle. In my opinion, in this case it would be best we override the mapping of this trouble-some enity with xml mapping. We can override single / multiple entities with xml mapping. So we would use annotation for our mainly-supported database, and a xml file for each other database.

Note: we just need to override one single class , so it is not a big deal.
Read more from my example 
[Example to override annotation with XML](http://goo.gl/GKy3x)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Justin, Pascal for guiding me to the right direction. I was also facing the same issue with Hibernate 3.5.3. Your research and pointers to the right classes had helped me identify the issue and do a fix.

For the benefit for those who are still stuck with Hibernate 3.5 and using oid + byte[] + @LoB combination, following is what I have done to fix the issue.

1. I created a custom BlobType extending MaterializedBlobType and overriding the set and the get methods with the oid style access.

   ```
   public class CustomBlobType extends MaterializedBlobType {

   private static final String POSTGRESQL_DIALECT = PostgreSQLDialect.class.getName();

   /**
    * Currently set dialect.
    */
   private String dialect = hibernateConfiguration.getProperty(Environment.DIALECT);

   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see org.hibernate.type.AbstractBynaryType#set(java.sql.PreparedStatement, java.lang.Object, int)
    */
   @Override
   public void set(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
       byte[] internalValue = toInternalFormat(value);

       if (POSTGRESQL_DIALECT.equals(dialect)) {
           try {

   //I had access to sessionFactory through a custom sessionFactory wrapper.
   st.setBlob(index, Hibernate.createBlob(internalValue, sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()));
               } catch (SystemException e) {
                   throw new HibernateException(e);
               }
           } else {
               st.setBytes(index, internalValue);
           }
       }

   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see org.hibernate.type.AbstractBynaryType#get(java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String)
    */
   @Override
   public Object get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
       Blob blob = rs.getBlob(name);
       if (rs.wasNull()) {
           return null;
       }
       int length = (int) blob.length();
       return toExternalFormat(blob.getBytes(1, length));
     }
   }
   ```

   2. Register the CustomBlobType with Hibernate. Following is what i did to achieve that.

      ```
      hibernateConfiguration= new AnnotationConfiguration();
      Mappings mappings = hibernateConfiguration.createMappings();
      mappings.addTypeDef("materialized_blob", "x.y.z.BlobType", null);
      ```