# Hibernate annotations image storing

Tags: image, hibernate, struts2, annotations

I'm using struts2 and hibernate and I want to know how to store and retrieve images from database using hibernate annotations in the POJO class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as following

```
private byte[] imageBefore;

@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
@Column (name = "IMAGE_BEFORE") 
public byte[] getImageBefore() {
    return imageBefore;
}
```

refer to this link if you're not using annotations and for a complete reference

Answer (score 2):

Best way to store images in the database in in format of `Byte array`like you have to upload images using struts2 file upload utility and den pass it on to hibernate as `byte[] image`;

in your mapping you have to do something like

```
@Column( name = "IMAGE" )
@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
private byte[] image;
```

How to use annotation for this is very well described in the following thread

[proper hibernate annotation for byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte)

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
@Lob
private byte[] picture;
```

Comment: In my case, this doesn't works, Gives error - `Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [image] in table [productlines]; found [mediumblob (Types#LONGVARBINARY)], but expecting [tinyblob (Types#VARBINARY)]`