# Cast an Object to ByteArray

Tags: java

I've got a function:

```java
public static Object receviceSigAndData(Socket s) {
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        DataInputStream din2 = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        int sig_len = 0;
        sig_len = din2.readInt();
        byte[] sig = new byte[sig_len];
        din2.readFully(sig);
        int data_len = 0;
        data_len = din2.readInt();
        data = new byte[data_len];
        dsa.update(data);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (Object) data;
}
```

The function returns an `Object`. If the `Object` is a byte array, how do I cast the `Object` to `byte[]`?

```
byte[] b = (?)receviceSigAndData(socket);
```

Thanks

Comment: why not just return a `byte[]` from the method? It seems as though you're unnecessarily casting it to an `Object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 2 helper methods to get you to serialize and deserialize byte arrays as objects.

```
public static Object deserializeBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    ByteArrayInputStream bytesIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bytesIn);
    Object obj = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return obj;
}


public static byte[] serializeObject(Object obj) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.flush();
    byte[] bytes = bytesOut.toByteArray();
    bytesOut.close();
    oos.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Got here after giving out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380) reached via [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114510](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114510) and this totally made tuesday. Tests are now failing, but the use case is now at last working.

Comment: Pointless. They already are objects, and the OP already has his own serialization and deserialization based on `DataInput/OutputStream`.

Answer (score 13):

By looking at your code:

- you don't need to upcast the return value to `Object`: since it's an upcast, it's implicitly done (a `byte[]` is statically also an `Object`)
- you can easily cast an `Object` to a `byte[]` by using a specific downcast:

```java
byte[] a = (byte[]) obj
```

- a method like yours that returns an `Object` is completely pointless, signatures are meant to be useful and informative. Returning an `Object` is the least informative thing that you can do. If your method is meant to return a `byte[]`, then its return value should be of `byte[]` type