# How to store image into postgres database using hibernate

Tags: image, hibernate, postgresql, store, hibernate-mapping

I want to store image into database using hibernate and Java.  I am using postgres database

I tried `bytea` data type to store image and `byte[]` data type in hibernate pojo.

I used the following code,

```
CREATE TABLE photo
(
  "photo_name" bytea
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE photo OWNER TO postgres;
```

Hibernate Pojo

```
public class PhotoEntity {

byte[] name;

public byte[] getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(byte[] name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

but it gives error at time of mapping.
please give me any reference to do this.

Comment: Show us your real code, and tell us the exact and complete error message, which probably contains meaningful information and is not just a "you did something wrong" flag.

Comment: hi sir,  error occure at time of mapping because bytea is not map with  byte[] or byte also.so confused which data type i used instead of byte[] or byte in hibernate pojo.

Comment: You must supply the exact mapping code you used, and the error(s) you get, for anyone to help you.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Hibernate via JPA2, you may need the `@Lob` annotation, though I'm not sure if that's for `oid` or `bytea` fields. See:

[proper hibernate annotation for byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte)

There's also a [Hibernate dev blog post](http://in.relation.to/15492.lace) that's quite informative.

If you're using Hibernate via XML mappings or its own annotations dialect, please show your exact code and error message(s).

See also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte).

Comment: I suspect when `@Lob` mapping to `OID` chances are Hibernate won't `lo_unlink` the LOB neither before nor after losing reference to it via `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc.