# How to read bytea image data from PostgreSQL with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, bytea

I have PostgreSQL database and there is column 'image' with datatype 'bytea'. I cannot modify columns or database configurations. JPA annotated POJO contains followign mapping

```
@Column(name="image")
private byte[] image;
```

The returned data is in following format (this is just a sample)

```
WF5ClN6RlpLZ0hJTUdNQ1FJWmkwcFVGSUdNQ0lDWUE5TUEvanRFeElwK2x0M2tBQUFBQVNVVk9SSzVDWUlJPQo=
```

When I write this data to file (.jpeg)  photo viewer says "this is corrupted file". I also understand that actual image byte data looks different from above sample. I read some blogs which mentioned that PostgreSQL applies hexadecimal conversion to bytea data. How to restore it to original data with or without JPA ?

Database - PostgresSQL Version 9.5.1

Driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1205-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your example should work (if you don't use the `@Lob` annotation; see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte)). How did you get that base64 representation exactly? Are you sure that's not something, that's outputted (and possibly transformed) by a view-related service? (Please try to debug the `@Entity` to see, what's exactly get back to the `image` property & what do you set to that property before saving).

Comment: Are you sure that this is an image? How do you store it? Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17667480/1700321).

Comment: @pozs decoded with apache codec Base64 class and javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter parseBase64Binary() as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned Data looks as if it is base64 encoded. You have to decode it back to binary data before writing to file.

For further information to decode look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Comment: Yes you are right its 64Base ecoded. Thanx. Added complete code below, may be useful for others.

Answer (score 12):

Try to annotate you entity with `@Lob`

```
@Lob
@Column(name="image")
private byte[] image;
```

If you are using hibernate implementation you can add `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")` in column too.

```
@Lob
@Column(name="image")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
private byte[] image;
```

Comment: I would say if you are using hibernate you **have to** add the `@Type` otherwise you get `found [bytea (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [oid (Types#BLOB)` error on startup

Answer (score 7):

**ImageEntity**

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ImageEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="image")
    private byte[] image;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**ImageRepository**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<ImageEntity, Long> {
}
```

**Test**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)
public class ImageDaoTest {

    @Resource
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;

    @Test
    public void testImage() throws IOException {

        // Read an image from disk. Assume test.png exists
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.png")) {
            int length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        byte[] image = out.toByteArray();

        // Store image to DB
        ImageEntity imageEntiry = new ImageEntity();
        imageEntiry.setImage(image);
        long imageEntiryId = imageRepository.save(imageEntiry).getId();

        // Retrieve image from DB
        ImageEntity resultImageEntiry = imageRepository.findOne(imageEntiryId);
        byte[] resultImage = resultImageEntiry.getImage();

        // Compare retrieved image with source image by byte to byte comparison
        for (int i = 0; i < resultImage.length; i++) {
            TestCase.assertEquals(image[i], resultImage[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

It works against Postgres 9.5.0-1 with 9.4.1207.jre7 jdbc driver.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding complete code which may be useful for others (skipping try/catch),

```
String base64EncryptedImage = new String(image);
decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncryptedImage);
ImageOutputStream out = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("D://abc.png"));
out.write(decoded);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**insert an image, you would use:**

```
  //Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
    LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).getLargeObjectAPI();

    // Create a new large object
    int oid = lobj.create(LargeObjectManager.READ | LargeObjectManager.WRITE);

    // Open the large object for writing
    LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.WRITE);

    // Now open the file
    File file = new File("myimage.gif");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Copy the data from the file to the large object
    byte buf[] = new byte[2048];
    int s, tl = 0;
    while ((s = fis.read(buf, 0, 2048)) > 0) {
        obj.write(buf, 0, s);
        tl += s;
    }

    // Close the large object
    obj.close();

// Now insert the row into imageslo
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO imageslo VALUES (?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, file.getName());
ps.setInt(2, oid);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
fis.close();

// Finally, commit the transaction.
conn.commit();
```

**Retrieving the image from the Large Object:**

```
// All LargeObject API calls must be within a transaction block
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

// Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).getLargeObjectAPI();

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT imgoid FROM imageslo WHERE imgname = ?");
ps.setString(1, "myimage.gif");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // Open the large object for reading
    int oid = rs.getInt(1);
    LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.READ);

    // Read the data
    byte buf[] = new byte[obj.size()];
    obj.read(buf, 0, obj.size());
    // Do something with the data read here

    // Close the object
    obj.close();
}
rs.close();
ps.close();

// Finally, commit the transaction.
conn.commit();
```

Comment: I am using JPA, I cannot do all this stuff like going back to JDBC. I think this solution still will not work with hex encoded data.

Comment: The `bytea` type and large objects are completely separated in PostgreSQL.