# The best way to store images from URL in Postgres

Tags: java, image, postgresql, url, crud

I need to build a simple CRUD application and connect it to a database, class looks like

```
public class Employee 
{ 
private int id;
private String email;
private String address;
private String(Datatype ???) avatarURL;
}
```

The database i use is Postgres

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  address VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  avatarURL Datatype(???)
);
```

Obviously, the image value should look like a direct URL to an image, not such as a text and be shown as a picture on a page. And since I can update a picture I want this field to have a "Choose a file" field as well as "Or load from URL", so I can change a picture from local file on a computer. What a datatype should I use?

Comment: You should store the file in another location, and save the string to that location (for instance, a URL to the image) as the reference. Then you should get the image from the location

Comment: Do you want to store image URLs or image data? If its data you should consider datatype `blob` in PostgreSQL and `byte[]` in Java.

Comment: I want to store them just as a field to my Employee object

Comment: I've heard that this approach is very harmful to a database, it makes the performance very slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read bytea image data from postgresSQL with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505424/how-to-read-bytea-image-data-from-postgressql-with-jpa)

Comment: Ok, there's a solution to real FILE, not URL