# How to Store doc, jpeg, pdf files in postgreSQL using java

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, save, blob

**In a web application I want to store all doc, jpeg, pdf files in postgreSQL database.** 
I know it can also be done by storing it on file system and storing its path in db, but I am not looking for that solution.  I want to know following things:

1. What should be data type for a table.
2. Does it maintain formatting of doc ?
3. And how storing it in postgreSQL can be achieved using java, hibernate technology. IS it required to create nativeSQL query?

Any pointers for this issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You'll want to store the binary data as the `bytea` type. Here is an example using JDBC and Postgres `bytea`:

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html

This post about using `bytea` and Hibernate might be of some use: [proper hibernate annotation for byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte)