# eclipselink and postresql large objects on Glasshfish

Tags: entity, eclipselink

I have a trouble whit eclipselink and postresql

I use Glassfish 3.1.2 and his eclipselink for connect to a postgresql database with persistence, in my table I have an postresql large object file that in my entity is convert into bytearray with @lob annotation.

When I try to save a new record with the file postgresql say this:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "attoid" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The same code on Hibernate work well.

I have try to search on google or here but I don't found nothing...someone can help me?

Comment: Yet another exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte

Comment: @Chris Travers i have to disagree with you, this problem is about eclipselink, while link with you provided contains answer specific for hibernate