# Download BLOB data from MySQL database via Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, blob

I've a little problem; when I trying to **download** data (picture,audio...) from Mysql database.I'm getting damaged file so the file size is 1kb.I've changed file extension just in case but always got same results.

Please can anyone help me?

I've tried with this code :

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

     public class DownloadFileFromDb {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onurDB";
        final String user = "onur";
        final String pass = "onurdb958";
        String SQL = "SELECT FILENAME FROM `PIC_STORE` WHERE `ID`=?";

        Connection conn = null;
        java.sql.PreparedStatement smt = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting...");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
            System.out.println("Connection successful..\nNow creating query...");

            smt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            smt.setString(1, "4");  //in this row we have a png picture
            rs = smt.executeQuery();

            output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/MacbookPro/Downloads/pic.png"));
            System.out.println("Getting file please be patient..");

            while (rs.next()) {

                input = rs.getBinaryStream("FILENAME"); //get it from col name
                int r = 0;

    /*
    *there I've tried with array but nothing changed..Like this :
    * byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    * int r = 0;
    * while((r = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
    *        out.write(buffer,0,r);}
    */

                while ((r = input.read()) != -1) {
                    output.write(r);

                }
            }
            System.out.println("File writing complete !");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Class not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Connection failed!");   
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File writing error..!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(rs != null){
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    smt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.println("Connot close connecton!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

there is downloaded file : [pic.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaMSl.png) file size is 12 byte.

***THANKS FOR ALL.***

Comment: FILENAME is the content of your File?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes My Table columns are ID,FILENAME,PICTURE,FILETYPE.

Comment: show your table description

Comment: the content of your image is not PICTURE ? It would be more obvious than FILENAME

Comment: @NicolasFilotto tahnks for replay , now i try to correct it

Comment: @NicolasFilotto OW MY GOD!How I miss... it solved :) Just I changed the SQL query maked it PICTURE and input = rs.getBinary(1); Thank you so much

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

 public class DownloadFileFromDb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onurDB";
    final String user = "onur";
    final String pass = "onurdb958";
    String SQL = "SELECT PICTURE FROM `PIC_STORE` WHERE `ID`=?"; //Here I mistakenly wrote 'FILANAME' here instead of a 'PICTURE'

    Connection conn = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement smt = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connecting...");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Connection successful..\nNow creating query...");

        smt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        smt.setString(1, "4");  //in this row we have a png picture
        rs = smt.executeQuery();

        output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/MacbookPro/Downloads/pic.png"));
        System.out.println("Getting file please be patient..");

        while (rs.next()) {

            input = rs.getBinaryStream("FILENAME"); //get it from col name
            int r = 0;
            while ((r = input.read()) != -1) {
                output.write(r);

            }
        }
        System.out.println("File writing complete !");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Class not found!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection failed!");   
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File writing error..!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(rs != null){
            try {
                input.close();
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                smt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Connot close connecton!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}

}
```