# byte[] data in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring application that uses MySQL as database.

I want to migrate the application from MySQL to Postgres, and it seems that I can not declare byte[] array:

I have this column:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
private byte[] data.
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "tinyblob" does not exist
```

Is there a way to achive this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You need to specify the PostgreSQL dialect in your JPA provider, you currently seem to be using the MySQL dialect when connecting to PostgreSQL. You may want to specify which JPA provider (Hibernate by the looks of it) you're using.

Comment: You also need to make sure that your obfuscation layer (=ORM) uses `bytea` as the data type for that column.

Comment: In addition to what @MarkRotteveel said, there is no need to use the `@Type` annotation for this.

Comment: In the entity class definition, if I declare only Type, I have an the error from the post.

Comment: check this link : http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/tinyblob

Comment: I found also this, but doesn't work for me to use byte[] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte

Answer (score 8):

In your PostgreSQL DB Table, set the `data` column datatype to `bytea` **NOT** `bytea[]`
and in your POJO class:

`@Column(name="name_of_your_column")
private byte[] data;`

Leave out the `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")` annotation.

That should work just fine.