# Convert Inputstream from an UploadedFile from Primefaces to a String

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, inputstream

Iam trying to save an InputStream from Primefaces `UploadedFile` into a String. 
The reason for this is, that I cant figure out how to persist an inputstream with hibernate.

Following Code is given:

```
public String saveDocumentInDatabase(final UploadedFile pFile) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = pFile.getInputstream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] tmp = baos.toByteArray();
    return new String(tmp, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}


public StreamedContent downloadUploadedFile(final JoinExam pJoinExam){
    assertNotNull(pJoinExam.getSavedDocument());

    String tmp = pJoinExam.getSavedDocument().trim();
    java.io.InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tmp.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    return new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, "application/pdf",
            "Protocol" + pJoinExam.getPruefling().getMatrNr()+ ".pdf");
}
```

In my JoinExam I have following Attribute.

```
@Lob
@Column
private String savedDocument;
```

My Attention is to save the uploadedFile´s inputStream into my String `savedDocument`, which should "represent" my uploaded File.
When I want to download my "uploaded File" I want to get my `savedDocument` String and convert it back an inputStream.
The achieved inputStream will be used to create an `DefaultStreamedContent`
so I can download the File with primefaces `<p:fileDownload />` -Tag.

My problem is, that the inputstream seems to lose some data while converting into a String or the String seems to loose some data while converting back to the inputstream.
When I download the File and try to open it, an error pops up, saying that the filed could not be opened.

Thank you for any adivce

EDIT:  When I upload and download .txt-Files it works, but it is not working with pdf-Files.

Comment: So it effectively is not a PrimeFaces issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you can store a PDF content into a `@Lob String` field? PDF is a binary file and those are usually handled with `@Lob byte[]` field. Error saying that the file could not be opened implies that it was corrupted.

Comment: is it possible to persist an byte[] attribute  with hibernate ?

Comment: @sergeantSalty yes but it also depends on the database e.g. Oracle has both `CLOB` and `BLOB` fields. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3739047/1602555 for more information.

Comment: Thank you guys it is working perfectly with the byteArray !