# Compatible type of bytearray for Postgres, MySQL, HSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate, blob, hsqldb

I have a column which looks like this:

```
@Column(name = "somedata", columnDefinition = "bytea")
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
private byte[] somedata;
```

This `bytea` column definition works fine with PostgreSQL, but for testing purposes I use HSQL which is not supporting it, only if I rename it to `blob`. I want to use MySQL for a second datasource and that is also not supporting the mentioned HSQL datatype.

So my question is that is there an universal solution for byte array type that can work for both three of datasources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proper hibernate annotation for byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677380/proper-hibernate-annotation-for-byte)

Comment: I read this one but it didn't work for me

Comment: The Standard SQL type name VARBINARY is supported by HSQLDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it work for both three of databases in this way:

Now the types are:

1. HSQL-blob
2. PostgreSQL-bytea
3. MySQL-mediumblob

```
@Column(name = "somedata", length = 5 * 1024 * 1024)
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
@Lob
private byte[] somedata;
```